# Can natural number be an ordered pair?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

I’m supposed to prove that natural number $n$ cannot be an ordered pair. The definition for ordered pair is $(x,y) = \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ and for the definition of natural numbers we use the definitions of set theory.

I don’t know if this should be done with induction or what. Any clues are helpful. Thanks!

Comment: “...for the definition of natural numbers we use the definitions of set theory” — What are those? That’s pretty important. All you have to do is write them out and show that they don’t work with $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that an ordered pair has between $1$ and $2$ elements. This limits the number of cases to exactly $1$ and $2$.

Or, you can note that $\varnothing$ is never an element of an ordered pair, and an ordered pair is never empty.

---

Note that if you are using Zermelo's natural numbers, then $2=\{1\}=\{\{0\}\}=\{\{\varnothing\}\}=\langle\varnothing,\varnothing\rangle$. But the above assumes that you're working with the standard von Neumann definition where $n=\{0,\dots,n-1\}$.

Comment: What do you mean that an ordered pair has between 1 and 2 elements? I don’t quite understand.

Comment: @Miia:  the ordered pair $(a,a)$ has one element, whereas $(a,b)$ with $a\ne b$ has $2$